# Storing NLP Models in Git Repo vs S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, machine-learning, nlp

What is the best way to store NLP Models? I have multiple NLP models which are about 800MB in size in total. My code will load the models in memory at start up time. However I am wondering what is the best way to store the models. Should I store it in git repo and then I can load directly from local system or should I store in an external location like S3 and load it from there? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each? Or do people use some other method which I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1):

Very good question, while very few people pay attention to it.

Here are a few factors I point out:

- Cost of (1) storing files  (2) bandwidth: cost of
  downloading/uploading resources (models, etc)
- Lazy download: Not all the resources are required for running an NLP systems. It's a headache for the end-point user to download many resources that are not nearly useful for their purpose. In other words, the system should download (ideally itself) any resource needed for its purpose, when it's required.
- Convenience.

And options are:

- **S3:** The benefit is that if you have it working, it's convenient. But the issue is that someone familiar with S3 and Amazon AWS has to monitor the system for failures/payments/etc. And it's often expensive. Not only you pay for having the space, more importantly you also pay for band-width. If you have resources like word-embeddings or dictionaries (in addition to your models), each of which taking a few GB, it's not hard to hit terabytes of bandwidth usage. [AI2](http://allenai.org) uses S3 and they have a [simple Scala system](https://github.com/allenai/datastore) for their usage. Their system is "lazy" i.e. your program downloads (and caches) a given resource only when it's required.
- **Keep it in the repo:** certainly checking in big binary files in the repo is not a good idea, unless you use [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/?utm_source=github_site&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gitlfs) to keep the big files outside your git history. Even with this, I'm not sure how you'll make programmatic calls to your files. Like you have to have scripts and instructions for users to manually download the files, etc (which is ugly).

I'm adding these two options too:

- **Maven dependency:** Basically package everything in Jar files, deploy them and add them as dependencies. We used to use this, and some ppl still use it (e.g. StanfordNLP ppl, they ask you to add models as maven dependency). I personally do not recommend it, mainly because maven is not designed to take care of big resources (Like sometimes it hangs, etc).  And this approach is not lazy, meaning that maven downloads EVERYTHING at once at compile/run time (e.g. when trying StanfordCoreNLP for the first time, you'll HAVE TO download a few Gigabytes of files that you might never need to use, which is a headache). Also, if you're a Java user you know that working with classpath is a BIGx10 headache.
- **Your own server:** Install file manager server (like [Minio](http://minio.io)), store your files there and whenever required, send programmatic calls to the server in your desired language ([their APIs are available for different languages in their github page](https://github.com/minio)). [We've written a convenient Java system to access it in Java](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-datastore) that might come handy to you. This gives you the lazy behavior (like S3), while not being expensive (unlike S3) (Basically you'd get all the benefits of S3).

Just to summarize my opinion: I've tried S3 in past, and it was pretty convenient, but it was expensive. Since we have a server that's often idle we are using Minio and we're happy about it. I'd go with this option, if you have a reliable remote server to store your files.

Answer (score 0):

Do your NLP models need to be version controlled? Do you ever need to revert back to a previous NLP model? If these are not the case, storing your artifacts in an S3 bucket is certainly sufficient. If you are planning on storing many NLP models for a long period of time, I also recommend [AWS Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/). Glacier is an extremely cost effective for long term storage.

Comment: I plan on atleast having the current and previous version, incase of any problems. What if I store it in git? Is there any disadvantage other than having an extremely huge git repo ?

Comment: Never mind. This is a good enough description. https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

Comment: I didn't know there was a soft github disk limit. Lesson learned!